# Does AMP HTML allow unofficial custom elements

Tags: web-component, amp-html

Will an AMP page work with an unofficial custom component?

I can imagine getting an official one is best for spreading usage but for just 1 site which wants to program in some custom component does it need to get its component approved as official or it can just make one and include it in its own code?

https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-components.md

Comment: See here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/creating-your-first-amp-component/index.html

Answer (score 6):

No. An unofficial custom component would have to break the "AMP-conforming content may not have any JavaScript." constraint.

I'd suggest either following the approach described in the "Service-specific JavaScript built-in to a component" section: https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/spec/amp-html-components.md or working with the project to get your desired component included.