# How to create my own custom-element with Google AMP?

Tags: amp-html

I've a custom video player, and I'd like to create a "custom-element" to invoke the layout and functionality using Google AMP. I've saw documentation about how to use the current components that AMP HTML library provides. Any info about how to create my own component will be really appreciated.

Something like:

```
<amp-my-own-video-player
    layout="responsive"
    width="480" height="270">
</amp-my-own-video-player>
```

Comment: See here: https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/creating-your-first-amp-component/index.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to a Developer Advocate at Google in [this SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33672611/does-amp-html-allow-unofficial-custom-elements), you can't create your own custom element. The only way you'll be able to do it is to [contribute](https://github.com/ampproject/amphtml/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md) or be a member of the AMP HTML team.

Answer (score 3):

You can try contributing to the Github repo by following the instructions [here](https://www.ampproject.org/contribute/) but if it is a proprietary video player, I doubt you'll be able to get a PR accepted.